# Django - Images aren't loading in second app

Tags: python, django

I got two apps 1. main, 2. contact inside my Django project. Both use the base.html file to get the head and the footer. Inside the footer is a image which perfectly work in the main app but inside the contact app it is not shown, there is no images displayed.
I tryed to change the settings but everything was set correct. I implement the static and media root

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and inside the urls.py I do

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If i open the inspector in firefox the path is the right one but the console throws a 404

> GET http://localhost:8000/static/media/contact/contact_image.jpg 404
>   (Not Found)
>   How couldnt it work when the media folder is in the root of the app and the settings are the same in both apps?

[image]

Comment: what are the static folder contains?

Comment: contains only css and js

Comment: http://localhost:8000/static/contact/contact_image.jpg and http://localhost:8000/media/contact/contact_image.jpg both are different no use of combining the, two url like you mentioned

Comment: yes so i use the media folder cause my images are stored there but I tried to put the image in the static folder but that also doesnt work. Do u have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

can you try

`http://localhost:8000/media/contact/contact_image.jpg`

and also can you add urlpatterns this:

`urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: the http://localhost:8000/media/contact/contact_image.jpg works so I can see the picture but also with adding static to the urlpatterns doesnt solve the problem :(